# Start Turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm Korean Student. So I cannot speak English very well. Please excuse me..

I want to setup turtlebot.. so i did do this page step by step.

http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Robot%20Setup

http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/SDK%20Setup

http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup

Complete..

And I connect my netbook to Turtlebot.

And Enter the command "roscore" -> (another terminal) "sudo service turtlebot start"

and I see the message "service start pid : 123" like this..

but When i enter the command "rostopic list", the message is just "/ros" and "/ros_arg" like this..

i mean that service of turtlebot cannot start..

i don't know why.. please help me t.t

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30361/start-turtlebot/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-23**:
My netbook is Asus ZX6

**Comment by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on 2012-03-23**:
Does the command "sudo service turtlebot start" display any errors?

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-24**:
No.. "turtlebot start/running. process 1355"
But when i enter the commane "sudo service turtlebot start" one more, "turtlebot start/running. process 1515"
and i check list using the command "rostopic list"
terminal shows that "ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!"

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-03-24**:
Check that ros is running by running
"ps -ef | grep ros"
If ros is running, check to make sure that you have setup the network correctly.

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-25**:
Thanks.. when i enter the command "ps -ef | grep ros", i see the list "grep --color=auto ros"
but.. when i enter the command "rostopic list", i see the message "ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!"
t.t help me...

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-25**:
perhaps.. i cannot use turtlebot on Ubuntu 11.10 ?

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-03-25**:
You should see some other processes running, try "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch"

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-03-25**:
If that works, 'roscd turtlebot_bringup/upstart && sudo ./install.bash wlan0' should install the proper scripts in /etc. Replace wlan0 with the correct name for your wifi device. http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Robot%20Install#Configure_Upstart

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-25**:
should i enter the command "sudo ./install.bash ai", if name of my wifi device is 'ai' ??

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-03-26**:
That sounds like your kernel driver. You want the device name that shows up in ifconfig. it is usually eth0 or wlan0 or eth1

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-26**:
Thank you i succeed this step ^^;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that starting a roscore before executing a launch file prevents the launch file from completing correctly. I suspect the same holds for starting services. Do not run roscore. Only run "sudo service turtlebot start".

---

Originally posted by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) with karma: 328 on 2012-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-03-25**:
I'm not sure if this is helpful, but here goes. You should be able to run roscore independent of roslaunch, though there are some nuances. roslaunch will start roscore if it is not already running. If you start roscore, then start roslaunch then stop roslaunch, roscore will keep running.

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-03-25**:
However if you start roscore, then start roslaunch, then restart roscore, the nodes you launched with roslaunch may not reconnect properly. If I recall correclty, Dynamic reconfigure reconnects, but image_view will not.

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-03-25**:
However you are right that on the TurtleBot you should just need to run the service. You can however stop the service and start roscore manually but that it probably just complicating matters.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

'sudo service turtlebot start' will start roscore so you don't need to run that separately.

I am making a complete guess that it is a permissions problem. You may want to look at the logs or try starting minimal.launch and kinect.launch manually as the turtlebot user instead of using 'sudo service turtlebot start'

Also, you may want to try turtlebot_config from this ticket to make sure your udev rules are correct.
https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/125

---

Originally posted by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) with karma: 403 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1